# Flink and Kinesis stream app for non continous data

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, amazon-kinesis

We've built a Flink app to process data from Kinesis stream. The execution flow of the app contains basic operations for filtering data based on registered types, assigning watermarks based on event timestamps, map, process and aggregate functions applied on windows of data of 5 mins as shown below:

```
    final SingleOutputStreamOperator<Object> inputStream = env.addSource(consumer)
            .setParallelism(..)
            .filter(..)
            .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(..);

    // Processing flow
    inputStream
            .map(..)
            .keyBy(..)
            .window(..)
            .sideOutputLateData(outputTag)
            .aggregate(aggregateFunction, processWindowFunction);

    // store processed data to external storage
    AsyncDataStream.unorderedWait(...);
```

Ref code for my watermark assigner:

```
    @Override
public void onEvent(@NonNull final MetricSegment metricSegment,
                    final long eventTimestamp,
                    @NonNull final WatermarkOutput watermarkOutput) {
    if (eventTimestamp > eventMaxTimestamp) {
        currentMaxTimestamp = Instant.now().toEpochMilli();
    }
    eventMaxTimestamp = Math.max(eventMaxTimestamp, eventTimestamp);
}

@Override
public void onPeriodicEmit(@NonNull final WatermarkOutput watermarkOutput) {
    final Instant maxEventTimestamp = Instant.ofEpochMilli(eventMaxTimestamp);
    final Duration timeElaspsed = Duration.between(Instant.ofEpochMilli(lastCurrentTimestamp), Instant.now());
    if (timeElaspsed.getSeconds() >= emitWatermarkIntervalSec) {
        final long watermarkTimestamp = maxEventTimestamp.plus(1, ChronoUnit.MINUTES).toEpochMilli();
        watermarkOutput.emitWatermark(new Watermark(watermarkTimestamp));
    }
}
```

Now this app was working with good performance (in terms of latency in order of few seconds) sometime back. However, recently there was a change in the upstream system post which the data in Kinesis stream gets published to the stream in bursts (only for 2-3 hours every day). Post this change, we have seen a huge spike in latency of our app (measured using flink `gauge` method by recording start time in first filter method and then emitting the metric in Async method by calculating the diff in the timetamp at that point from the start timestmap). Wondering if there is any issue in using Flink apps with Kinesis stream for bursty traffic/non continuous stream of data?

Answer (score 0):

Since the input stream is now idle for long periods of time, this is probably creating situations where the watermarks are held up. If this is the case, then I would expect to see a lot of variance in the latency, as it would (probably) only be the final windows for each burst whose results are delayed until the arrival of the next burst.

Comment: Ahh, I see, but that is probably not the case in my app because I am emitting watermarks in onPeriodicEmit function based on 20s elapsed from the time when first event of max event time came in. So even for the final windows, it would emit watermark post 20s of the first event and stay at that watermark only until the next burst comes in. Adding the code reference in my question for reference if something seems fishy there.

Comment: Detecting bursts and advancing the watermark to flush out results makes sense -- but I can't tell if the code you shared will work correctly because there are too many references to variables that either aren't initialized or aren't used in this snippet.